# Cannot fix this error.... "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c

I have this function...

```
  void monitor_write_hex(u32int n)
       {
           if(n <= 9) {
               char *c = n+'0';
               monitor_write(c);
           } else {
               char *c = n+'7';
               monitor_write(c);
           }
       }
```

And I getting the error:

> monitor.c:149:13: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast [-Wint-conversion] char* c = n+'0';

I'm hoping someone can help me fix it

Comment: `c` is a pointer, yet you assign it an integer value. Exactly as the error says.

Comment: Are you attempting to use `+` to concatenate characters into a string? In C `+` is merely addition for numeric types.

Comment: Can you please explain what you want the code to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the line `char *c = n+'0'` (and in the analogous line below) on the left side of the assignment you have `char *c` (a pointer to `char`), on the right an integral value of `n+'0'`. The compiler warns you that you most probably don't want to assign one type to a different type.

I suspect it might be true and if your `monitor_write` function expects a pointer, you should pass it a pointer to an already existing variable, something like (though not seeing the complete code one is not completely sure if that's the right solution):

```
char c = n+'0';
monitor_write(&c);
```

Comment: Solved it! Thank you

Comment: Caution, if `monitor_write` is expecting a nul-terminated string, then the code above is wrong, but may only fail intermittently if you are unlucky.

Answer (score 0):

In these statements

```
   char *c = n+'0';
   char *c = n+'7';
```

You are declaring a pointer but initializing it with an integer.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
   void monitor_write_hex(u32int n)
   {
       if(n <= 9) {
           char c[2] = { n+'0' };
           monitor_write(c);
       } else {
           char c[2] = { n+'7' };
           monitor_write(c);
       }
   }
```

provided that the function `monitor_write` awaits a string of the type `char *` as an argument.